# missing ';' before identifier error - not able to run MPI example

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to run the [following](http://www.lam-mpi.org/tutorials/one-step/ezstart.php) example using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and C++ project.
I am getting a lot of errors. For example:

> Error 1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'get_next_work_item'

in the following code:

```
#include <mpi.h>

#define WORKTAG 1
#define DIETAG 2


/* Local functions */

static void master(void);
static void slave(void);
static unit_of_work_t get_next_work_item(void);
static void process_results(unit_result_t result);
static unit_result_t do_work(unit_of_work_t work);
```

I guess I am missing an include. Why this error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this [example](http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/att-0739/one2one_varios.cpp) you have:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

#define WORKTAG 1
#define DIETAG 2

typedef int unit_of_work_t;
typedef int unit_result_t;
```

So now your `unit_of_work` is not recognized from the compiler. So, maybe you should consider making a `typedef` or include some extra header.

Answer (score 1):

This is because compiler is not able to recognize

```
unit_of_work_t
```

data type. Probably you are missing header file for this...

Comment: I just have to pay more attention to the example. It is a template - I must replace this reference with something else (like `int`) for example. What i lame question I asked.